# Transformación logarítmica antes de auto.arima in R?

Tags: r

Tengo datos, de series temporales, a los que he aplicado la transformación logarítmica porque era necesaria, ¿sabéis si la función auto.arima, reconocerá que apliqué esta transformación? o es necesario hacer algo extra en la programación para que auto.arima lo reconozca?

```
STL = log(ST.van)          ### Aplicando transformación log a datos 
         originales
        library(forecast) 
        fit <- auto.arima(STL)     ### Modelo con datos transformados
        fit <- auto.arima(ST.van)  ### Modelo con datos originales
```

¿`auto.arima()` reconocerá si aplique esta transformación?

Comment: Muestra por favor lo que intentaste

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Ya publiqué lo que intenté.

Comment: Estuve leyendo al respecto y encontré que auto.arima, automaticamente realiza transformación si los datos lo requieren.